# type List<dynamic> is not a subtype of Map<String,dynamic>

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile-development

I have been able to follow a few tutorials on Flutter about basic UI design, and am new to API calls. I think I need to convert types after making the API call, but I have no idea how.

Note: I know this is a lot of code in one file, but I will separate the API call file and custom class file from my main file

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Future<Country> fetchAlbum() async {
  final response = await http.get('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all');

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    // If the server did return a 200 OK response,
    // then parse the JSON.
    return Country.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
  } else {
    // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
    // then throw an exception.
    throw Exception('Failed to load album');
  }
}

class Country {
  final String name;
  final List<String> topLevelDomain;
  final String alpha2Code;
  final String alpha3Code;
  final String callingCodes;
  final String capital;
  final String region;
  final String subregion;
  final int population;
  final List<int> latlng;
  final String demonym;
  final int area;
  final int gini;
  final List<String> timezones;
  final List<String> borders;
  final String nativeName;
  final int numericCode;
  final List<String> currencies;
  final List<String> translations;
  final String flag;
  final String cioc;

  Country({
    @required this.name,
    @required this.topLevelDomain,
    @required this.alpha2Code,
    @required this.alpha3Code,
    @required this.callingCodes,
    @required this.capital,
    @required this.region,
    @required this.subregion,
    @required this.population,
    @required this.latlng,
    @required this.demonym,
    @required this.area,
    @required this.gini,
    @required this.timezones,
    @required this.borders,
    @required this.nativeName,
    @required this.numericCode,
    @required this.currencies,
    @required this.translations,
    @required this.flag,
    @required this.cioc,
  });

  factory Country.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Country(
      name: json['name'],
      topLevelDomain: json['topLevelDomain'],
      alpha2Code: json['alpha2Code'],
      alpha3Code: json['alpha3Code'],
      callingCodes: json['callingCodes'],
      capital: json['capital'],
      region: json['region'],
      subregion: json['subregion'],
      population: json['population'],
      latlng: json['latlng'],
      demonym: json['demonym'],
      area: json['area'],
      gini: json['gini'],
      timezones: json['timezones'],
      borders: json['borders'],
      nativeName: json['nativeName'],
      numericCode: json['numericCode'],
      currencies: json['currencies'],
      translations: json['translations'],
      flag: json['flag'],
      cioc: json['cioc'],
    );
  }
}

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  Future<Country> futureAlbum;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    futureAlbum = fetchAlbum();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Fetch Data Example',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Fetch Data Example'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: FutureBuilder<Country>(
            future: futureAlbum,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return Text(snapshot.data.name);
              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Text("${snapshot.error}");
              }

              // By default, show a loading spinner.
              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is what my emulator screen looks like: http://i1.imgrr.com/18Z/7512_Screenshot1599026660.png

Comment: Try using `factory Country.fromJson(Map<dynamic, dynamic> json)`

Comment: type List<dynamic> is not a sybtype of Map<dynamic, dynamic>

Comment: Try using factory Country.fromJson(dynamic json)

Answer (score 0):

line 12 'return Country.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));'

I think the type of 'json.decode(response.body)' is a 'List', but parameter type is Map in here. Maybe your response is a list of Country objects, but it's returning 1 Country object. That's why you got this error

Comment: That's probably it; what do i do to change the return type?

Comment: it depends on you. that API returns a list. so you can get the list first, run the loop and convert each element (type is Map) to your object and do what you want

Comment: I'm new to Flutter; can you please write out the code and explain it to me?

Comment: `Future<List> fetchAlbum() async {
  final response = await http.get('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all');

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    // If the server did return a 200 OK response,
    // then parse the JSON.
    List list = [];
    json.decode(response.body).forEach((e) =>
      list.add(Country.fromJson(e))
    );
    return list;
  } else {
    // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
    // then throw an exception.
    throw Exception('Failed to load album');
  }
}`

Comment: you have to change the function return Future<List> if you want to use a list of country. or return only 1 Country which you want to use

Comment: I do want to return a list of countries. 
I tried replacing the code and got an error on fetchAlbum(); saying this:

A value of type 'Future<List<dynamic>>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Future<Country>'.Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'Future<Country>'

Comment: `Future<List> futureAlbum;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    futureAlbum = fetchAlbum();
  }`

Comment: line 109. Please check all your code and change that flow to List. you want a list, please make sure the type of value is List, not Country.

Comment: line 125, Make sure you want to display on screen 1 country or a list of countries and modify builder.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the above line. Here is the updated code:
https://pastebin.pl/view/5d540a16

Comment: type List<dynamic> is not a subtype of List<String>

Answer (score 0):

Your API returns `List` instead of `Map`.

You need to map each element as a `Country`.

```
Future<List<Country>> fetchAlbum() async {
  final response = await http.get('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all');

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
     List<Country> countryList = ((json.decode(response.body) as List).map((i) => Country.fromJson(i)).toList();
    return countryList;
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to load album');
  }
}
```

Comment: My emulator screen says "type List<dynamic> is not a subtype of List<String>". 
Here is the code: https://pastebin.pl/view/9e948ee9

Comment: Please refer to this link to generate your factory code properly. Paste your json response here and it will generate the class for you

https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/